# Counting columns of a space separated file

Tags: c++, count, stdin

My question concerns the use of `std::count` (or another appropriate function) to count the columns of a space separated file.

I currently use something like this:

```
  std::ifstream inFile("file"); 
  int lines = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile), 
             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');
```

to count the lines.

Since all the lines are equal (same amount of data), would something like

```
  std::ifstream inFile("file"); 
  int columns = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile), 
             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>('\n'), ' ') + 1;
```

do what I need?

Thanks

EDIT:

I mean, if in `"file"` there is data like `1 2` or `1 [many spaces here]    2`, would the value of `columns` anyway be 2 or not?

Comment: @Ed: because I have only one machine and currently is occupied with heavy computations, in the meanwhile I am thinking about how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll count spaces, not columns. You need to tokenize your line, e.g. by [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tokenizer/)

Comment: In simple cases, `number of columns = number of spaces + 1`.

Comment: I see. And what if I am not allowed (don't ask why) to use external libraries?

Comment: you can use c-style [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/), I didn't recommend it because you specified [C++] and because [strtok has problems](http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/strtok.html).

Comment: yes, I use C++ and I would like to use it as much as possible. Thanks for the reply